# using ZEND_Layout, having different Layouts

Tags: zend-framework, zend-layout

I asked a similar question again, but I don´t get it. I wanted to try using different layouts at first just for understanding ZEND_Layout.

I have two layout files in my layout path: application\layouts\scripts
layout.phtml
login.phtml

First I want to use login.phtml, because of that I defined it in my application.ini, here is a snippet:

```
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.layout.layout = "login"
```

This of course works, I get the layout I wanted. After leaving the page, I want to change the layout (before I read the tutorial): [http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/learning.layout.usage.html][1]
So I put the following line in my Controller indexAction:

```
$layout->setLayout('layout');
```

I just get an error message, "undefined Variable $layout ..."

It must be quite simple, but it doesn´t work, where is the error? I´m missing some basic information I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need the $layout variable set.

If you are doing it from your controller, the quickest way.. is to just use..

```
 $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('layout');
```

Comment: ok, I tried, I get teh layout, I want and additional an error message: Plugin by name 'SetLayout' was not found in the registry

Comment: sorry, this works, I forgot somewhere another snippet